# How summarise count equal rows between factor columns R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have followed data example

```
df <- tibble(var1 = factor(c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c")),
         var2 = factor(c("a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d")))
```

I would like to summarise this data as one row and three columns (1X3) in tibble format. Where the first column show the counting of similar row values, the second column show the counting of different and the third column the total of values with final format as:

```
final <- tibble(equal = 2, different = 6, total = 8)
```

thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  summarise(equal = sum(as.numeric(var1) == as.numeric(var2)),
            different = sum(as.numeric(var1) != as.numeric(var2)),
            total = n())
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  equal different total
  <int>     <int> <int>
1     2         6     8
```

Comment: I appreciate your help...but I add incorrect my data so, i fix my data in question. if you still know how to help me, I would appreciate it. I one of these columns I not have all of levels that have in other.